# My Batch script cannot match the cover JPG images when muxing files into a MKV

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, matroska

I wrote the code and I want to use it for my archive. Thanks for helping me improve it.

The folders containing the files are as follows (ex.):

Got folder  `/S01`, `/s02`, `/s0n`...

```
/S01/01.mkv, 02.mkv,..., cover.jpg
/S02/01.mkv, 02.mkv,..., cover.jpg
```

In each subfolder there is a file named `cover.jpg` that I want to attach to all the files in that folder but I can not modify my code to work properly.

The written code could not identify the `cover.jpg` in each folder.

Here is the code:

```
@ECHO OFF
For /R %%A IN (*.mkv
) Do (
  "C:/Program Files/MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~dpnxAtmp" --no- ^
  attachments --no-chapters --no-global-tags --no-subtitles --title ^"^" ^
  --language 0:und --language 1:en --track-name 0: --track-name 1: "%%~fA" ^
  --attachment-name cover.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^ 
  "%*cover.jpg"
  if errorlevel 2 ( 
      echo errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
      del/f "%%~fA" echo Warnings generated during remuxing to "%%~A", original file deleted
    ) else (
      del/f "%%~fA" echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~A", original file deleted
    ) & for /R %%A IN (*.mkvtmp) do ren "%%~fA" "%**.mkv" & CLS
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal 

cd /d "%~dp0" & title <nul & title .\%~nx0 

for /f tokens^=* %%A IN ('where /r . *.mkv^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe/vei mkvtmp
')Do (call ) &<con: "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "%%~fAtmp" ^
 --no-attachments --no-chapters --no-global-tags --no-subtitles --title ^"^" ^
 --language 0:und --language 1:en --track-name 0: --track-name 1: "%%~dpnxA" ^
 --attachment-name cover.jpg --attachment-mime-type image/jpeg --attach-file ^
 "%%~dpAcover.jpg" & call %:^) %errorlevel% "%%~fA"

for /R %%A IN (*.mkvtmp)do >nul move /y "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.mkv"
<con: endlocal && %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /t -1 && goto :EOF 
     
%:^)
if %~1 equ 0 ( 
      del /q /f "%~2" && echo[Successfully remuxed to "%~nx2", original file deleted
    ) else if %~1 equ 1 ( echo[errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
    ) else if %~1 equ 2 echo[Warnings generated during remuxing to "%~nx2", original file deleted
      exit /b
```

---

**1.** You need `SETLOCAL`

```bat
ErrorLevel
When run from a batch file, SETLOCAL will always set an ERRORLEVEL.
If given a valid argument or no arguments, a new environment is created %ERRORLEVEL% = 0
If bad parameters given, %ERRORLEVEL% = 1
```

**2.** Replace `for /R` to `for /F` with `where /r` (recursively) list your all your files `.mkv` avoid **`.mkvtmp`** file with `findstr /v`

```bat
for /f tokens^=* %%A IN ('where /r . *.mkv^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe/vei mkvtmp
```

**3.** Start your loop resetting `errorlevel` with `(call )` // credit to **[@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl)**

```bat
... ')Do (call ) &<con: ...
```

**4.** Implement a function, where you can pass the current `errorlevel` as the parameter (`%~1 == %errorlevel%`) also the current file (`%~2 == %%~fA`)

```bat
%:^)
if %~1 equ 0 ( 
      ...
    ) else if %~1 equ 1 ( ...
    ) else if %~1 equ 2 ...
      exit /b
```

**5.** Inside this function (label `:^)`), let the `errorlevel`/`%1`parameter be treated by conditional `if else if else` conditions:

```bat
%:^)
if %~1 equ 0 ( 
      del /q /f "%~2" && echo[Successfully remuxed to "%~nx2", original file deleted
    ) else if %~1 equ 1( echo[errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
    ) else if %~1 equ 2 echo[Warnings generated during remuxing to "%~nx2", original file deleted
      exit /b
```

---

**Obs.: 1** Replace your in your code `"%*cover.jpg"` to `"%%~dpAcover.jpg"`, the `for /f (or /R)` loop and `mkvmerge.exe` unfortunately they will not translate or choose a file based on these string **`%*cover.jpg`**:

**Obs.: 2** The last command (`ren`) will not replace existent file, you can try to replace `ren` to `move /y`, using target name `"%**.mkv" "%%~dpnA.mkv"`

```bat
for /R %%A IN (*.mkvtmp) do ren "%%~fA" "%**.mkv"

for /R %%A IN (*.mkvtmp)do >nul move /y "%%~fA" "%%~dpnA.mkv"
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)
- [`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Timeout /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)
- [`Findstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)